# Android process has encountered a memory leak issue with messagequeue

Tags: memory-leaks, android-camera

By dumping the meminfo of the cameraserver process, it was discovered that Ashmem (anonymous shared memory) is consuming as much as 95MB of memory.
Applications Memory Usage (in Kilobytes):
Uptime: 18540763 Realtime: 18590599
Pss  Private  Private  SwapPss      Rss     Heap     Heap     Heap
Total    Dirty    Clean    Dirty    Total     Size    Alloc     Free

---

Native Heap     2584     2584        0       60     2584        0        0        0
Dalvik Heap        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
Stack      468      468        0       12      468
**Ashmem    95372    95312        0        0    95552**
Other dev       17        0        0        0      600
.so mmap     3581      984     2220     2900    14484
Other mmap       25       24        0       32      552
Unknown      260      260        0      544      260
TOTAL   105855    99632     2236     3548   114500        0        0      0

App Summary
Pss(KB)                        Rss(KB)
------                         ------
Java Heap:        0                              0
Native Heap:     2584                           2584
Code:     3204                           14484
Stack:      468                            468
Graphics:        0                              0
**Private Other:    95612**
System:     3987
Unknown:                                  96964

TOTAL PSS:    105855       TOTAL RSS:    114500    TOTAL SWAP PSS:     3548

So I attempted to analyze the memory increment by capturing pmap and using strace.
Finally, after comparing the pmap data before and after the operation, I found that after multiple calls to the camera, there is a probability that the MessageQueue is not being released And the MessageQueue belongs to Ashmem memory.

11535: /system/bin/cameraserver
Address           Kbytes     PSS   Dirty    Swap Mode  Mapping
000000716870e000   32772    3137    3136       0 rw-s- MessageQueue (deleted)
000000716d70f000   32772    2313    2312       0 rw-s- MessageQueue (deleted)
000000716f710000   32772    3161    3160       0 rw-s- MessageQueue (deleted)
0000007174712000   32772    3101    3100       0 rw-s- MessageQueue (deleted)
0000007177713000   32772    3153    3152       0 rw-s- MessageQueue (deleted)
000000717f713000   32772    3037    3036       0 rw-s- MessageQueue (deleted)
000000718e8e4000    1028      29      28       0 rw-s- MessageQueue (deleted)
000000718e9e5000    1028     197     196       0 rw-s- MessageQueue (deleted)
00000071906e3000    1028     197     196       0 rw-s- MessageQueue (deleted)
00000071908e5000    1028      25      24       0 rw-s- MessageQueue (deleted)
00000071909e6000    1028       1       0       0 rw-s- MessageQueue (deleted)
0000007190ae7000    1028     189     188       0 rw-s- MessageQueue (deleted)

is anyone knows how the MessageQueue buffer work？please tell me！

Comment: Please format your question.